# Computing a determinant

Tags: determinant

Suppose we have a $10 \times 10$ matrix $A$ which has $0$'s on the main diagonal (so that the trace of $A$ is $0$). Also suppose that $A^2=I$. How can we find a determinant of $A+2I$?

Based on [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698284/spectrum-of-a-large-matrix), I tried to find eigenvalues, as in find $\lambda$ so that $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible. I have trouble again doing this, given the hypotheses here that are different than those of my previous question. How can I proceed in finding eigenvalues so I can construct a spectrum and find the determinant?

Comment: $A^2 = I$ means that the eigenvalues are either plus or minus 1, as, $x = A^2 x = \lambda^2 x$ for any eigenvalue of $A$. Since the trace of $A$ is zero, the sum of the eigenvalues is zero, and thus the eigenvalues are 1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, ie, 5 1's and 5 -1's.